# php > 7.0 устарел mbstring

Tags: php

mbstring же устарел в 7х версиях пхп. 
так почему же функции `mb_` продолжают работать, без deprecated?

Comment: Устарел != будет удален в следующей версии(deprecated).

Comment: почему это устарел-то? Не путаете с `function overloading` настройкой или ещё с чем?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.configuration.php